# Whats the purpose of the primitive getter/setter in Field?

Tags: java, reflection

In the documentation for `public Object get(Object obj)` method in the [`Field`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) class it is stated that

> The value is automatically wrapped in an object if it has a primitive
>   type.

and for `public void set(Object obj, Object value)` that

> If the underlying field is of a primitive type, an unwrapping
>   conversion is attempted to convert the new value to a value of a
>   primitive type.

So am I right that the only purpose of the specific primitive getter and setter like `getInt` and `setInt` is to prevent a redundant type conversion?
Since this code works fine

```
public class Test{  
    int i = 1;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Test inst = new Test();
        Class<?> clazz = inst.getClass();
        Field fi = clazz.getDeclaredField("i");
        int ii = (int) fi.get(inst);
        Integer iii = new Integer(ii * 2);
        fi.set(inst, iii);
    }
}
```

I am asking if someone knows a scenario that needs you to use these methods aside from performance reasons.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you have answered the question yourself. You refer to the documentation that basically states that a primitive will be wrapped / unwrapped as necessary if you use the Object version of the methods.

Comment: Originally it was only for performance reasons, though there could be an incidental reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's for both type-safety and efficiency. Think about it the other way - the `get*()` methos are the *intended* way to access primitive fields, and doing so via `get()` just happens to work as well but requires boxing/unboxing.

In other words the only reason to use `get()` on a primitive field is if you don't know its type ahead of time.